# Changing project from GAC to Bin deployment

Tags: deployment

I have a third party dll that I have reference in my sharepoint webpart project.  The provider of the dll didn't sign it and will not recompile it for me.  So I have to change my project to from a GAC deployed project to a bin deployed project. 
When I look at under the Package.package and then go to the Manifest. I see

```
`<Assembly Location="My.dll" DeploymentTarget="GlobalAssemblyCache">`
```

I cannot figure out how to modify this section.  It is not editable.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a fan for Bin deployment, because it involves CAS policies to be added to the solution... What you can do is to sign it yourself.  Check the following link that contains lots of ressources on how to sign an already built assembly. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/clr/thread/76ae6443-cbf3-47aa-87b3-0e6ac81cafe6

Comment: Looks like link is broken.  Found one here http://nishantrana.wordpress.com/2010/03/08/sign-an-already-built-assembly/ and am testing.

Comment: Should do the trick !

Answer (score 5):

You can change this setting in your Visual Studio 2010 SharePoint project. Click on the project in 
Visual Studio and in the properties window, change the Assembly Deployment Target from **GlobalAssemblyCache** to **WebApplication**.

see snapshot sample here http://i51.tinypic.com/2vl8wsp.jpg